# Full dotted path (any level path) with path_match in dynamic_templates

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-template

I have this document

```
{
    "text_foo": "lorem ipsum",
    "one":{
        "two":{
            "three":{
                "text_bar": "dolor sit amet"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to acomplish: I need dynamic template, that will match any properties starting with "text_"
example:

```
"mappings" : {
    "dynamic_templates":[
    {
            "text":{
                "match": "text_*",
                "path_match": "*.text_*",
                "match_mapping_type": "*",   
                "mapping":{"type":"text","analyzer":"myCustomAnalyzer"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## Question 1:

Can i use `"match"` and `"path_match"` together? (Like in my example)

## Question 2:

Will `"path_match":"*.text_*"` match whole path `"one.two.three.text_*"` or only `"one.text_*"?

## Question 3:

Will `"path_match":"*.text_*"` match also root property `"text_foo"`?

## Question 4:

If only solution is use regular expresions (`"match_pattern":"regex"`), will regular expresion match against whole path `"one.two.three.text_bar"` or only against `"text_bar"`?